# Meaning of "we're rather flat" in context

Tags: expressions, idioms, meaning-in-context

From *Yellow Slugs* by H.C. Bailey:

> He went to the room where Eddie lay. The doctor was there, and turned from the bedside to confer with him. “Not too bad. We’ve put in a long sleep. Quite quiet since we waked. Very thirsty. Taken milk with a dash of coffee nicely. But **we’re rather flat**.”

What does the boldened bit, “we’re rather flat”, mean?

Comment: I'm not sure it's general reference, the word being so polysemous, but RHK Webster's has: **flat** 13[/44] lacking vitality or animation; lifeless; dull.  **PS** Thank you; I've just added 'flat' to my list of 'secondary modifiers' ['flat broke'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context it's hard to be sure, but I'd take "flat" to mean that they're still tired physically and/or emotionally. Certainly that's how I'd have intended it.

Answer (score 0):

I think *flat* here is used to bean:

- without variation, or change.